# How does the Reeder Mac app animate lists when switching folders?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4, core-animation, appkit

Initially I was under the impression that it uses the table row slideup/down animations while inserting/deleting new rows but I doubt if it's doing that as it does it so fluidly even with thousands of items in the list (otherwise it would take a lot of time for the deletions/insertions to work).

Am I right in my assumption that it's simply attaching a new instance of the News list at the bottom of the screen, shrinking the above one while the one at the bottom expands to fill up space?

UPDATE:

Please see this video of what I mean: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4960327/ReederAnim.mov

Comment: Can you post a link to a screencast of the behaviour you are describing? Many people will not have a copy of Reeder handy.

Comment: Sure good point! Let me do that.

Comment: Did you try to ask Silvio Rizzi ? Maybe he's gonna tell you his secret :)

Comment: I don't think so :) But I have figured it out. a) he's not relying on 10.7 SDK to use the Table List Header sections and using his own implementation. b) he's actually shrinking the whole container hosting the NStableView which gives it that cool effect. c) he's lazy loading and lazy sorting rows which get added in the background and as you scroll, so that gives it the speed in which it loads that amount of data.

Comment: @strange: I've been wondering how he did this myself. It doesn't seem to act like a normal NSTableView, yet class-dumping it reveals that it is, in fact, a NSTableView. Any more insight on what's going on here?

Comment: I figured it out. It is indeed a NSTableView however he's added additional animation support and 'floating section headers' to NSTableView to support OS before 10.7 came out. He is then simply animating the frame of the container and adding a new one at the bottom. The 'resize' frame causes the rows to shrink vertically. It's quite clever but a lot of work which you don't wanna do with 10.7 onwards as you then can't use the 10.7 View based table support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can not tell you exactly how Silvio Rizzi made this, but as you see in the playback, a list view is added behind the shown list view, and the front list view fades out (.alpha = 0.0;) while the list view behind it expands its height per row.

When you desicate it frame by frame it becomes quite clear what he does, and it is really not that advanced. But I have to admit, with the white "milky" polished interface, it looks quite neat.

In addition, you can see that while animating, the background list view only renders the top 7  entries (hopefully calculated by dividing the view height with the average height of the cells shown) making the list view quick to load. Then afterwards, he can load an extended array of cells once you start scrolling, or in a background thread starting once the animation is complete.